# Is the story of the liberation of a Pisacha mentioned in the Samkhya Sutra found in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, reference-request, sankhya, shad-darshana

In the Samkhya Sutra, the fourth chapter (Akhyayika) mentions many stories to convey the message of Sankhya philosophy. One such story is the story of a Pisacha (goblin).

> पिशाचवदन्यार्थोपदेशेऽपि
> piśācavadanyārthopadeśe'pi
> - Samkhya Sutra 4.2

From the traditional commentary, one can see that the story goes like this: When Krishna was instructing Arjuna on the battlefield, there was a Pisacha nearby behind a bush. The moment that Pisacha heard the conversation and got the knowledge, he immediately got liberated (as it does not have any physical body).

The point it wants to make is that if someone is intelligent, he or she will get the knowledge by listening just for once. According to Samkhya, knowledge (Viveka jnana) alone is sufficient to deliver liberation. If someone does not get it by listening once, he should listen again and again (another verse tells that).

Now, my question is whether this story of Pisacha is found in Mahabharata. If it is found, please quote from Mahabharata along with the chapter number etc.

There is absolutely no problem if the story is not mentioned in the Mahabharata. That won't weaken the Samkhya position. It is fine if they use a fictional character as a metaphor to convey their point.

However, many such stories mentioned in that chapter are also found in other scriptures. For example, the Samkhya Sutra mentions the story of Indra and Virochana from the Upanishads to convey the message that after listening Manana or contemplation is needed. That's why I was wondering whether this story is found in Mahabharata.